# Go言語でtimeパッケージを使用してからundefinedというエラーが出る

Tags: go

## 実行していること

Go言語で日本の現在時刻を読み込むためにtimeパッケージを用いてコードを記述していたのですが、下記エラーメッセージが出るようになってしまいました。

timeに関する記述をコメントアウトしてもエラー文が消えません。
ローカルのデーターベースに投稿内容をimportする際に投稿時刻も入れる目的で現在時刻を取得していました。

## エラー内容

```
$ go build

# time
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.19.3/libexec/src/time/sleep.go:51:11: undefined: Time
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.19.3/libexec/src/time/sleep.go:156:31: undefined: Time
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.19.3/libexec/src/time/tick.go:12:11: undefined: Time
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.19.3/libexec/src/time/format.go:508:9: undefined: Time
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.19.3/libexec/src/time/format.go:539:9: undefined: Time
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.19.3/libexec/src/time/format.go:598:9: undefined: Time
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.19.3/libexec/src/time/format.go:614:9: undefined: Time
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.19.3/libexec/src/time/format.go:958:35: undefined: Time
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.19.3/libexec/src/time/format.go:967:60: undefined: Time
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.19.3/libexec/src/time/format.go:971:69: undefined: Time
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.19.3/libexec/src/time/sleep.go:156:31: too many errors
```

go buildを実行すると上記エラーが出ます。
timeに関するコードをすべてコメントアウトしてもエラーが消えません。

## 実行していたコード

```
t := time.Now().UTC()
tokyo, err := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Tokyo")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("日本の現在時刻取得失敗")
}
Date := t.In(tokyo)
```

上記コードで日本の現在時刻を取得しようとしていました。
正しい時刻が取得できなかったのですが、ローカル環境ではUTCを変更することが出来ないという記事を見つけたのでそちらは問題ありません。

そのまま実行しようとしたらエラー文が消えなくなってしまいました。
日本の現在時刻しようと何度かコードを実行したので、その際にエラーが出てしまったのかと思います。
(実行したコードは消してしまって残っておりません)

timeに関するコードをコメントアウトしてもエラーが消えないということは原因はどちらにあるのでしょうか？
どなたかご教授いただけると幸いです。
宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

Go のファイルが壊れているようです。
具体的には、`/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.19.3/libexec/src/time/time.go` が存在しないか、上書きされていませんか？

Go を再インストールしてみてはいかがでしょうか。

```
brew reinstall go
```